# What other markup syntax is closest to MediaWiki?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, mediawiki, geshi

GeShi is a syntax highlighting tool used by projects and vendors like MediaWiki and pastebin.com, respectively.

However, GeShi does not natively support MediaWiki markup syntax. What would be the closest "look alike" that I could use to highlight a MediaWiki template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt there is any.  MediaWiki's syntax is a bit unique.  It's more than just markup language for creating single text documents, it's for creating whole sites.  The difference is relations between documents: linking, redirections and embedding one into another (templates).

BTW creating good syntax highlight for MediaWiki syntax is not possible, and all this because of templates.  For example:

```
{{{!}}
! a !! b
{{!}}}
```

Above would be completely valid table on the English Wikipedia because `{{!}}` resolves to `|`, so exclamation marks in second line should be highlighted as in table, but you can't tell that if you're not able to resolve templates.  (However not-that-good highlight could be found in Vim).

Comment: Since 1.24, `{{!}}` is a built-in magic word! https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words#Other